# MVC filters called without reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with C#

I register my filters here:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new Auth.isiroradmin());
        filters.Add(new Auth.isadmin());
    }
}
```

And if I use it, it all fine, but somehow one of the filters get called on a class where I don't use it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace mynamespace.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Error
        public ActionResult error401()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Error 401";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I redirect to this page, if user has no permissions, but i get here endless redirect. Is there a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution:

I have to remove this line:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

from Global.asax.cs

Comment: RegisterGlobalFilters adds filters that need to be called automatically. 

I would remove the new filters added to the method, but leave the setup call in Global.asax in place.